# Java File Classes Processing Numeric Data

Tags: java

```
 public class AvgScore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File dataFile = new File("scores.dat");
        FileReader in;
        BufferedReader readFile;
        String score;
        double avgScore;
        double totalScores = 0;
        int numScores = 0;

        try {
            in = new FileReader(dataFile);
            readFile = new BufferedReader(in);
            while ((score = readFile.readLine()) != null) {
                numScores += 1;
                System.out.println(score);
                totalScores += Double.parseDouble(score);
            }
            avgScore = totalScores / numScores;
            System.out.println("Average = " + avgScore);
            readFile.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File does not exist or could not be found");
            System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get Tia

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
string: "Tia"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at AvgScore.main(AvgScore.java:18)

//My desired output I want is 

//Tia
//88
//Ben
//55
//Derek
//77
//John
//65
```

What mistakes am I making? The code seems solid to me.  Also, how could I code my program so that it will be able to recognize the highest and the lowest score because I want to output that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like you're just trying to parse something as a double/float which is not a double/float.  Check your input file.

Comment: Please take some time to format your code in the question.

Comment: What double value would you like `Tia` to be ?

Comment: Looks like you have string in file and you are trying to parse it to double. Make sure whatever you read from file and your logic match. Otherwise it won't work. As per your logic it looks like file will have only number but getting string also.

Comment: So `Tia` isn't a number. Surely this is obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **score** variable actually contains a String representation of a numerical value, in other words no space(s), tabs, blank lines (null Strings) or any alpha characters other than the period for a decimal point. For obvious reasons the **[Double.parseDouble()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_parsedouble.htm)** method can not convert these characters to a double data type and therefore throws the exception you are receiving. Only numerical values are allowed. You can check this by using the **[String.matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm)** method along with a [Regular Expression](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html):

Within your **while** loop:

```
// If 'score' is NOT a numerical value (contains alpha char's)
if (!score.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") { 
    // Skip code below and continue 'while' loop.
    // If it's not numerical value then it must 
    // be a name or a blank line
    continue; 
}
else {
    // 'score' DOES contain a numerical value...
    numScores++; // same as: numScores += 1; OR numScores = numScores + 1;
    System.out.println(score);
    totalScores += Double.parseDouble(score);
}
```

This is the explanation for the Regular Expression used within the **String.matches()** method:

[image]

Comment: My teacher wouldn't expect me to do that. In that .dat file I'm taking my information from every second line has just numbers. I'm been trying various methods like for loops and if statements to use that information to get my program working but I haven't been able to code something that works. How do you think I could code this?

Comment: Well, this would really depend on how the data within the text file is laid out. If there are no blank lines within the file and the data is as you show in your desired output example then just read the file twice for every **while** loop iteration. You can just add another readLine(). The **while** loop condition starts off by reading the first line. If you add another: `score = readLine();` directly above: `numScores += 1;` then this will read the second line. On the next iteration the **while** loop condition reads the 3rd line and so on and so on....